# IOS swift how can I get label text inside a TableView on label tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I have a TableView that has data inside of it via Labels. When you click the label the Tap registers but now **I would like to get the Data of the clicked label** and I am having a difficult time getting that done. I have the same functionality working for Buttons for instance this is how I do it for my buttons inside a TableView .

Button Click Event

```
      var locations = [String]()
      @IBOutlet weak var Location: UIButton!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TableSource.dataSource = self


    }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Registration_Search", for: indexPath)

        cell.Location.setTitle(locations[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

        cell.Location.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Registration_SearchController.Location_Click(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.Location.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }

   func Location_Click(sender: UIButton) {

         print(locations[sender.tag])


    }
```

That code above allows me to get the Data of any Button that is clicked . I now try to do the same for the Label but can't get the data that the Label has . This is my Code for the Label and oh the same are the same as above but different ViewController

```
      var locations = [String]()
      @IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TableSource.dataSource = self
        location.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }
            func tapFunctionn(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
   // I would like to get the data for the tapped label here
    print("Tapped")
}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Registration_Search", for: indexPath)

          cell.location.text = Locations[indexPath.row]
          let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(HomePageC.tapFunctionn))

    cell.location.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        return cell
    }
```

Again when I click the label it prints **Tapped** but can't get the actual data. In the Button function I could use **Sender.Tag** but the UITapGestureRecognizer does not have a Tag method . Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Just use the delegate method. Set the `UITableView` delegate to your `UIViewController` and make the class conform to the `UITableViewDelegate`

**For swift 3**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TableSource.dataSource = self
    TableSource.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    //access the label inside the cell
    print(cell.label?.text)
    //or you can access the array object
    //print(Locations[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: That would work except that I am trying to put it inside a function because things will get a lot complex down the road.

Comment: well you can always call functions from inside `didSelect` and pass appropriate information.

Comment: Thank you that is what was needed

Answer (score 3):

You can make something like that:

```
func tapFunctionn(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
  let view = recognizer.view
  let index = view?.tag
  print(index)
}
```

Comment: This actually comes very close to it, the Only issue with that code above is that it always inserts the value of the First column . I am using your code and will try it make it dynamic