# tapping on collection view item causes multiple selection in collection view, instead of single selection

Tags: ios, swift

I have one `UICollectionView` and a custom cell for it. The custom cell contains one `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`.

1. I want to change the background color of the `UIImageView`, when I tap that corresponding cell ( In `didSelectItemAt indexPath` method I want to access the custom cell properties). Is there any way to achieve this? Or should I need some alternate way?
2. Another problem I am getting that when I tap any item from that `UICollectionView`, multiple selection is happening. Means the reusable cells are also getting selected as well.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you working in swift?

Comment: Yes, I m working with swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

**1. Custom `UICollectionViewCell` class:**

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var testImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    //MARK: Lifecycle Methods
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        self.testImageView.image = nil
        self.testLabel.text = nil
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool{
        willSet{
            super.isSelected = newValue
            if newValue
            {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            }
            else
            {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` Method as:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
}
```

You can change the cell selection and default colors according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**For your first problem**

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40690561/4539192) link as it contains the explanation on how to access the cell and its properties. (It is for `UITableView` but the same thing can be done for a `UICollectionView`)

**For your second problem**

You will have to update your model on `didSelectRow` and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will have to set the color of the cell based on that model.

Another solution for your second point would be to store the selected `indexPath` in an
    array and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check if that `indexPath`
    is present in that array and set its color appropriately. Example:

```
var array = [Int]()
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //update model or
      array.append(indexPath.item)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //check model or
    if(array.contains(indexPath.item)){


    }else{

    }
}
```